# Select rows with multi-conditional requirements in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have five tables,their relationships were listed in pictures. I would like to write a query to display the first name, last name, street, city, state, and zip code of any customer who purchased a Foresters Best brand top coat between July 15, 2013, and July 31, 2013. If a customer purchased more than one such product, display the customer’s information only once in the output. Sort the output by state, last name, and then first name.

[image]

I am OK with query with only one conditions, but for this multiple(Maybe indented?) conditions, I am totally stuck. I can analyze the structure like this:

```
IN LGBRAND TABLE: Brand_ID = 23 ~ Brand_Name = "Foresters Best" 
inv_date from lginvoice where inv_date between "2013-7-15" and "2013-7-31"
prod_category from lgproduct = "Top Coat"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without sample data, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM LGCUSTOMER c
JOIN LGINVOICE i ON i.Cust_Code = c.Cust_Code
JOIN LGLINE l ON l.Inv_Num = i.Inv_Num
JOIN LGPRODUCT p ON p.Prod_SKU = l.Prod_SKU
JOIN LGBRAND b ON b.Brand_ID = p.Brand_ID
WHERE b.Brand_Name = 'Foresters Best' AND
      p.Prod_Category = 'Top Coat' AND
      i.Inv_Date BETWEEN '2013-07-15' AND '2013-07-31'
ORDER BY c.Cust_State, c.Cust_Lname, c.Cust_Fname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(Cust_Fname),distinct(Cust_Lname),distinct(Cust_Street),distinct(Cust_City),distinct(Cust_State),distinct(Cust_ZIP) from lgcustomer as cust
   join (select inv_num,cust_code from lginvoice where CAST(inv_date AS DATE) between '2013-07-15' and '2013-07-31') inv on inv.cust_code = cust.cust_code
   join (select inv_num, prod_sku from lgline) ll on ll.inv_num = inv.inv_num
   join (select prod_sku,prod_descipt, brand_id from lgproduct where prod_descipt like "%Top Coat%") lgp on lgp.prod_sku = ll.prod_sku
   join (select brand_id, brand_name from lgbrand where brand_name like "%Foresters Best%") lb on lb.brand_id = lgp.brand_id
   order by 5,2,1 desc
```